# How to Update Custom Fields Using json API

Tags: wordpress, phonegap, wordpress-json-api

Im using **json-api plugin** in wordpress to connect my DB info to an phonegap app i'm developping, i need help on how to change **custom fields** array using de **update_post** from the API.

can anyone give me an example on how to do it, or if it is possible to do it

Answer (score 0):

You want to use update post meta.

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'field-name', 'new_value');
```

Comment: in the API?
i'm not using php scripts, only html and json API, my question is if there are any chance of doing that using the API

Comment: Yes.  If what you're trying to do is make a call to your site using the API in order to change meta, you will still need to use this hook in some fashion.  You can set up an endpoint that makes a callback to a function that does this.  This is a good article that explains in some detail how to do it.  https://torquemag.io/2015/07/working-with-post-meta-data-using-the-wordpress-rest-api/